# Is there any meaning for $f(x)-f'(x)$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am looking for any special property or application for $f(x)-f'(x)$. Like if it represents something about the main function f.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you multiply by $e^{-x}$, the resulting expression in $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}f(x))$. Here, $e^{-x}$ is an example of an integrating factor, a technique which is often useful in solving differential equations.

Comment: Let $t$ is some variable, let $x=t/T$ with some small $T$, then $f(x)-f'(x)$ is approximation for value of $f(t-T)$.

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is a polynomial, then if any of its roots have multiplicity greater than $1$, these roots will be shared between $f$ and $f'$.  So, the multiple roots of $f$ are zeros of $f-f'$ with lower multiplicity.  So, you can apply a numerical method to find roots of $f-f'$ which might be faster than finding multiple roots of $f$ directly.

For example, the double root of $f$ at $x = 0$ might be more quickly found with Newton's method for initial guess close to zero by applying it to $f-f' = x^2-2x$ instead of $f = x^2$ directly.

[image]

This is definitely not a complete answer; just one possible application.

Comment: Answer will be better with example where finding roots of $f-f'$ is easier than finding multiple roots of $f$